# Adobe Flash/Animate - transformation point equivalent in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When you're using the Flash/Animate IDE and you select something on the stage with the Free Transform Tool, then move the transformation point (the white circle), what is it actually doing in frame script? `DisplayObject`s only have x and y properties, there's no transformX or transformY.

I have a MovieClip place on the stage through the Flash IDE with various transformations applied to it, and I would like to be able to replicate those in Actionscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating a display object in IDE, moving transformation point makes IDE move *everything inside that object* in reverse direction coordinates wise. It's like if you're moving a zero point of a local coordinates system, leaving everything else intact, the contents will then have their coordinates altered.

In order to simulate this behavior, you can nest your display object being created into a container sprite, then when your user drags transformation center, you move the wrapper sprite to the new coordinates and alter its nested object's ( the one with all the contents) coordinates by negative delta between old and new positions of virtual zero.